# Extract particular value from column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to better extract following:

I have following values in column:

```
\\v8pip1\90PI-200009-10.PV
```

I need to get just below, \\v8pip1\ is the same for all rows:

```
 90PI-200009-10.PV
```

thanks,
S

Comment: You can use substring or similar.

Comment: I know I could use somethign like substr(col,9,20) but looking for something flexible, let's say I want everything except \\v8pip1\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `regexp_replace`. This will consider string after second single backslash as second group and return it.

```
select regexp_replace
(col1,
  '^\\{2}(\w*)\\(.*)',
    '\2')
from  (
select '\\v8pip1\90PI-200009-10.PV' as col1 from dual union all 
select '\\first\second string' from dual )
```

Output

```
90PI-200009-10.PV
second string
```

Comment: thanks all, I need also the same for sql server, I probably will ask on sql server topic.

Comment: As this question was for oracle, please accept the answer which worked for you so the question could be closed.

Comment: both examples work. Thanks a lot, but it seems I can only check one answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use (following is just an example):

```
SELECT replace('\\v8pip1\90PI-200009-10.PV','\\v8pip1\','') FROM DUAL;
```

Output:

```
90PI-200009-10.PV
```

Comment: It works for MSSQL too `SELECT replace('\\v8pip1\90PI-200009-10.PV','\\v8pip1\','') X`

Answer (score 0):

For a more general solution using just standard string functions:

```
select substr(input_string, instr(input_string, '\', -1) + 1) as new_string
from   ...
```

Stating the obvious, `input_string` is the input string. `INSTR` finds the position of the LAST occurrence of '\' in the input string (that is what the minus sign means in the last argument, `-1`). Then `SUBSTR` reads from that position + 1 to the end of the string.